# Find duplicates that all equal the same value in another table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

this may be an easy query but I'm new and I can't figure it out.
I have a table with orders and another table with the location those orders came from. There is a common key between them. 
The problem is that one order can come from more than one location and I need to find the orders that came only from one location.

How do I make sure that all the duplicate order numbers have the same location and query only that order number once ?

Thanks in advance for help!

```
 t1                    t2
ordno | shortl62    shortl62 | loc
----------------     --------------
00567 | 128          128     | CA
00689 | 128          291     | LA
00567 | 291          321     | BI
00689 | 128          499     | GA
00567 | 321
00336 | 128
00189 | 499
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, with your very general question it is hard to give you an appropriate answer, but what you might want to do is the following: `JOIN` the 2 tables on the key column and then restrict the dataset with the `WHERE` clause...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Join Duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526207/sql-join-duplicate-records)  this question is very similar and will give you a good start to find your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work:

```
create table t11(col1 varchar(20),col2 varchar(20));
create table t22(col3 varchar(20),col4 varchar(20));

insert into t11 values('00567','128');
insert into t11 values('00689','128');
insert into t11 values('00567','291');
insert into t11 values('00689','128');
insert into t11 values('00336','321');
insert into t11 values('00336','128');
insert into t11 values('00189','499');

insert into t22 values('128','CA');
insert into t22 values('291','LA');
insert into t22 values('321','BI');
insert into t22 values('499','GA');

select col1 from(SELECT  col1 FROM t11,t22 where 
t11.col2=t22.col3 
and t11.col1 in (SELECT col1 FROM t11 group by col1 having count(col1)>1)
and t22.col4='CA') group by col1 having count(col1)>1;
```

output:

```
00689
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show us any DDL command, so let me create some example based on your question.

We have 2 tables, one with orders, second with locations for orders.

```
CREATE TABLE "ORDERS" ("ORDERID" NUMBER, "DATA" VARCHAR2(200), PRIMARY KEY("ORDERID"));
INSERT INTO "ORDERS" VALUES (1, 'test order 1');
INSERT INTO "ORDERS" VALUES (2, 'test order 2');
INSERT INTO "ORDERS" VALUES (3, 'test order 3');
INSERT INTO "ORDERS" VALUES (4, 'test order 4');

CREATE TABLE "LOCATIONS" ("LOCATIONID" NUMBER, "ORDERID" NUMBER, "CITY" VARCHAR2(200), PRIMARY KEY("LOCATIONID"));
INSERT INTO "LOCATIONS" VALUES (1,1, 'NEW YORK');
INSERT INTO "LOCATIONS" VALUES (2,1, 'CHICAGO');
INSERT INTO "LOCATIONS" VALUES (3,1, 'ATLANTA');
INSERT INTO "LOCATIONS" VALUES (4,2, 'SAN FRANCISCO');
INSERT INTO "LOCATIONS" VALUES (5,3, 'LOS ANGELES');
INSERT INTO "LOCATIONS" VALUES (6,3, 'LAS VEGAS');
INSERT INTO "LOCATIONS" VALUES (7,3, 'MOSCOW');
INSERT INTO "LOCATIONS" VALUES (8,4, 'PARIS');
```

The query in question is very simple select with subquery.

```
SELECT "ORDERS"."ORDERID", "ORDERS"."DATA"
FROM "ORDERS"
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM "LOCATIONS"
  WHERE "LOCATIONS"."ORDERID"="ORDERS"."ORDERID")=1 ;
```

The subquery gets the count for each order and the WHERE clausule asks, if that count equals 1.

But as for optimal datamodel, you should have 3 tables present, one for orders, second for possible locations and then the third table for M:N relation between orders and locations. This is for preventing data duplication as I presume many locations will be used many times over and over again.

Comment: I don't have access to the data model but here is how it kinda looks (Edited). 
Your  query is a helpful start but just to clarify. I want only the order numbers that all duplicates of that order have the same "loc". So if I run it in the above data for loc = CA I want to get only ordno 00689 and not 00567 or 00336.
Thanks again

Comment: @CretuRadu why not 00336 it is having only one location